# Why does clojure (if-not) macro call (not)?

Tags: clojure

The [if-not](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/if-not) macro in Clojure is implemented as the following as seen in [core.clj](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.10.1/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L767):

```clj
(defmacro if-not
  ([test then]
   `(if-not ~test ~then nil))
  ([test then else]
   `(if (not ~test) ~then ~else)))
```

It calls the [not](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/not) function on the condition value. What is the reason behind choosing to call `(not)` here instead of a simpler implemetation below?

```clj
(defmacro if-not
  ([test then]
   `(if ~test nil ~then))
  ([test then else]
   `(if ~test ~else ~then)))
```

Comment: Six of one, half a dozen of the other. Obviously either way works. They probably just wanted to keep it as a "direct translation" from `if-not` to `(if (not ...)))`

Comment: You might get an answer from the Clojure maintenance team at https://ask.clojure.org/

Comment: Their version has lower cognitive load than yours, frankly. Although code-wise yours is cooler.

Comment: It's not particularly idiomatic to put the `else` before the `then`, which makes it harder to understand. I find reading `(if (not ...) ...)` a bit easier. Either way this doesn't really seem like a question that belongs here but I may be wrong.